# How to calculate kinetic energy of emitted particle using Q-value?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Suppose a nucleus of given mass number, initially at rest emits an $\alpha$-particle. How can I calculate kinetic energy of the $\alpha$-particle using no other data except the $Q$-value of the reaction? Now $Q$-value of a reaction is $$(m_{product} - m_{reactant}) c^2$$ But the masses(not mass numbers but exact masses) of product and reactant are not given, so I am stuck.

Comment: I know that Q-value is the product of mass difference between product and reactant & velocity of light squared, but since I dont have the mass(not mass number, exact mass) of product or reactant, I am stuck

Comment: OK then; could you edit your question to include that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $Q$-value in physics is usually defined as $(M_{\text{final}} - M_{\text{initial}}) c^2  $

Use conservation of energy and conservation of momentum.

Now if you know what the parent atom is then you need to look up the data for the mass of the parent atom $M_P$, the mass of the daughter atom $M_D$ and the mass of a helium atom $m$.
Using the accurate value of the masses of the atoms  will take care of the alpha not having any electrons.
It is often the case that using the nucleon (mass) number is accurate enough for everything except finding the $Q$-value..

Otherwise you should find the kinetic energy of the alpha particle in terms of $M_D, m, c$ and $Q$.

Comment: Sir in case of beta decay we consider subtracting (Z+1)e^- in the daughter nuclei of A (Z+1) Y for nuclear mass calculation, even though we have just Ze- in the atom isnt ? Any reason

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The picture below has the details of what Mr. Farcher had said. Please read through the below picture.